# How can I update a json-file with a Django/Heroku structure?

Tags: jquery, json, django, heroku

I have set up a Django website https://www.wasjournalistenverdienen.de/ on Heroku and it is going alright. But I have one problem.

The autocomplete on this website is based on the [easyautocomplete](http://easyautocomplete.com/examples#examples-ddg) plugin in JS and a predefined JSON-file of German publisher names that is located in the static/-folder of my Django-structure.

The idea is that whenever someone enters a name that does not match the predefined keys of the JSON, this new name gets pushed into the JSON and next time someone starts typing in this name, the autocomplete also suggests this new option. This works fine when I check my Django locally. But the problem is that Heroku is ephermal and that any changes to the JSON are not saved. I tried to update the JSON through the IndexView and store the changes on heroku but the updated JSON is seemingly not saved. I also tried using AWS as a workaround, change a JSON there but then the problem becomes that the autocomplete cannot load the JSON as it comes from another server.

Has anyone experience with how to create at least temporary files via views.py on heroku and how to also reference to them in JS?

Here is the code that creates an updated JSON in the indexview:

```
entriesno = DataCollection.objects.count()
    model=Medium
    mediumno=Medium.objects.values("mediumname").distinct().count()
    with io.open('honoradar/static/honoradar/mediumsname.json', "r") as json_file:
        oldjsondata = json.load(json_file)
        all_db_entries=Medium.objects.values("mediumname").distinct()
        for entry in all_db_entries:
            mediumname=(entry["mediumname"])
            newentry={"name":mediumname.title(),"code":mediumname.title()}
            oldjsondata.append(newentry)
        seen = set()
        new_l = []
        for d in oldjsondata:
            t = tuple(d.items())
            if t not in seen:
                seen.add(t)
                new_l.append(d)
        with io.open('tmp/mediumsname_temporary.json', 'w+') as outfile:
                        data=json.dumps(new_l, ensure_ascii=False)
                        outfile.write(data)
```

Comment: You should store the data in the database and generate the JSON dynamically from there on demand.

Comment: Sure, this is what I am already doing. See code added up there. But in order to pass it to the JS, I have to store it somewhere for a short time, right? Or should I do it via an AJAX request?